# Facebook Canvas app - OAuth redirect gives 2 popups instead of Enhanced Auth Dialog

Tags: facebook, canvas, oauth, dialog

Created my first authorized canvas app for Facebook, with the scope including "email" and "publish_actions". When a user visits the app for the first time and they are not logged into FB but not authorized for the app, I do the recommended step of redirecting them to a URL:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=516329518442226&redirect_uri=https://apps.facebook.com/authorizedapp/&scope=email,publish_actions

However instead of the Enhanced Auth Dialog (a big gray-bordered rectangle with lots of info embedded in the page with no popup, for an example check out Angry Birds or some other popular app), Facebook is generating two popups in a row for mine.

The first says "**AuthorizedApp would like to access your public profile, friend list and email address.**" And if you click Okay, the second popup comes up immediately after and says "**AuthorizedApp would like to post to your friends on your behalf.**"

What gives? How do I get the new Enhanced Auth Dialog?? All the documentation says I should just automatically get the Enhanced Auth Dialog because everything else is phased out!

Comment: Are you looking at [this documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/)? That's the current auth dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is because you are requesting "publish_actions" permission which is an extended permission. The auth dialog always asks for the extended permissions with a second pop up.